# Using controller to edit database on click in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to have a button pass a query to the database when it's clicked. I'd like to have this set within a Controller that also stores requests and deletes requests.  I was able to write to the database using store() and destroy(), but my edit() function gives me routing trouble. What is the best method to edit records using a controller? How would you build the edit() function? Or...should I be using the Update() function? I'm a Laravel/PHP beginner, please explain your answers if you can. Thank you!!

Overview: The project is an employee records table. I want to click a button that changes the employment status of an employee. I already have buttons to add new employee and delete and employee using this same Controller.

### This is the route I set for the page:

```
Route::resource('employees', 'EmployeeController');
```

### This is the front end form code for the button:

```
$workers = DB::table('employees')->get();

@foreach($workers as $employee)
 {!! Form::open(array(
        'method' => 'edit',
        'route' => [ 'employees.edit', $employee->id]
                    )
                ) 
 !!}

<button type="submit">Release </button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
```

### This is my store function and destroy function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Confirm Both Fields Are Not Empty
    $this->validate($request, [
    'first_name' => 'required',
    'last_name' => 'required',
    ]);

    //Add a new employee using the request data

    $employee = new Employee;
    $employee->first_name = request('first_name');
    $employee->last_name = request('last_name');
    $employee->position = request('position');
    $employee->salary = request('salary');
    $employee->hire_date = request('hire_date');
    //$employee->attach = request('attach');


    //Save it to the database

    $employee->save();

    //And then redirect back to the Employees page

    return redirect('/employees');
  }


 public function destroy($id)
  {
    $employee = Employee::find($id);

    $destroysignal = $employee->delete();

    if($destroysignal) {
        return redirect('employees');
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't edit records, you update them. In your case you need an update() function in your controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $employee = Employee::findOrFail($id);
    $employee->employment_status = true; //or false or whatever your statuses are
    $employee->update();
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Employee updated!');
}
```

In your form, use the update route instead

```
{!! Form::model($employee, [
    'method' => 'PATCH', 
    'route' => ['employees.update', $employee->id]]) 
!!}

    <button type="submit">Release </button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When using resource routes, `'route' => [ 'employees.edit', $employee->id]` will most like to open a page where you want to edit the object. And the route will be bound to the `edit($id)` function of your controller.

With that said, the edit route doesn't need a form. A simple anchor would do

```
<a href="{{ route('employees.edit', $employee->id) }}">Edit Employee</a>
```

Comment: Awesome!! This worked for me. Just needed to add $id in "public function update(Request $request, $id)" to work for me. Thank you

Comment: Oh yeah, just forgot that `$id`. Sorry.